# facebook javascript api post photo via chrome needs refresh

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I'm trying to post photo on the client wall, it works great through Firefox, but when I'm trying doing the same through Chrome (or Explorer), the first time I'm using the application and install it, I don't get a response at all... When I'm refreshing the page and try again, it works fine and post the photo...

This is the code I'm using:

```
            var imgURL = obj.picture;
            FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
                message: obj.description,
                access_token: accessToken, 
                url: imgURL
            }, function (responsePhoto) {

                if (!responsePhoto || responsePhoto.error) {
                    if (!responsePhoto){
                            console.log(responsePhoto);
                            alert('An error has occured: please refresh and try again');
                    }
                    else  {
                        console.log(responsePhoto);
                        alert('An error has occured:' + responsePhoto.error + ' please refresh and try again');
                    }
                } else {
                    //alert('your photo has been uploaded');//('Post ID: ' + responsePhoto.id);
                }
            });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the user is logged in correctly in this scenario? (And I mean _checked_ as in actually _verified_, not _“yes, he should be …”_ or something.)

Comment: yes, he loggin in and just than the option to post the photo appears

Comment: What does `console.log(responsePhoto)` directly at the beginning of your callback function write out? And what does `console.log(accessToken)` bring, and what does the debug tool say about this access token?

Comment: acctually i just copy that code from existing one... so IDK.. but in the first time im installing the app and it doesnt work, it even wont show the alert...

Comment: I just gave you some tips for _debugging_ – so please try to implement them, instead of “IDK”-ing for an answer …

Comment: and thank you for that... what i ment was that I have the alert for the debugging, but it wont even pass the if statement...

Comment: That’s why I suggested making a debug output even _before_ any conditional statements.

Comment: the problem solved... there was somthing wrong with the flow, for some reason the user status was not change to connected after login, so we just loged him in again. wierd thou that with firefox there was no problem at all...